# Why in the left join the result shows a few rows under a column null

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to practice left join and facing issues with the null values.

These are two tables and have few details common highlighted in red
[image]
1st try - When I run an inner join, I get correct results matching 4 rows in red
Query is as under

```
select * from empl1 
inner join empl2 on empl1.empl_code=empl2.empl_code
```

2nd try - When I run a left join, I get all the 4 rows which are common, but rest 6 rows shows all null values- please see  the query as under

```
select * from empl2 
left join empl1 on empl2.empl_code=empl1.empl_code
```

3rd try - When I run a left join mentioning the column titles I get full values in all the columns except in designation column. In designation column, I get null values except for matching rows. Please see the query as under

```
SELECT empl1.empl_code, empl1.fullname, empl2.designation, empl1.salary, empl1.department,  empl1.tablename 
FROM Empl1
left join empl2 on empl1.empl_code = empl2.empl_code
```

Results for Try 1 and Try 2
[image]

Why am I facing problem in left join with null values? why the 2nd time I get values in all the columns and get null in designation?

Please help me understand

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [Please read how to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/5234334) . Also put data in terms of tables which could be copied rather than images.

Comment: That's the whole point of `LEFT JOIN`. The result contains all the rows in the first table. If there's a match in the second table, you get the columns from that table, otherwise you get `NULL`.

Comment: Read this tutorial about different types of joins: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: There's no 'problem' here

Answer (score 0):

Left join will give you all the records from `left` table and `null` for records which don't match.

In your `Try 3`, you are selecting `empl2.designation`, hence you are getting `null` for non matching records.

And in `try 2`, you won't get null, if you just `select empl2.* from empl2 left join....`. I belive you didn't give exact screenshot.

I encourage you to create demo on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler) and share your work if you have any other doubt.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in the first statement your LEFT JOIN is on the empl2, and your first column is empl2.empl_code being NULL, instead in the second statement your LEFT JOIN is on your table empl1, your first column is empl1.empl_code. Use the same table with the LEFT JOIN and you will see the same result.